# QtCreator doesn't show all debug symbols for android debug builds

Tags: android, qt, cmake

I am developing an  Android qt in the CMake build system.
I am building the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` and trying to debug the application on target android device, which is eigher a `Samsung S21 FE` (`arm64-v8a` platform), or an `Google Pixel 5` emulator (`x86_64` platform).
In both cases when i am hitting breakpoints i don't have all debug information available in Locas/expressions:

[image: Debug view]

I am using the Qt 6.4.2. Tried next NDK versions

1. `25.2.9519653`
2. `25.1.8937393`

What may be wrong with my setup?